# Reliably getting local realm path

Tags: ios, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I found that to get the realm path, usually this is used:

`Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL`

But as far I understand, it's possible to overwrite the default configuration, when using a synced realm for example - in which case I'm not sure what this default path returns. Sometimes it's also just nil.

The reason I need the local path is to be able to migrate the local realm to a synced realm, like described here: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5381

I see that these recipes use `Bundle.main.url` to get the path of the realm, but normally it seems to be stored in the `Documents` directory (am I doing something wrong?). So I defined the path like this:

`let documentsDirectoryUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!
documentsDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent("default.realm")`

Which seems to work, but I'm not sure this is safe, as I'm assuming this will always be the default path... unless I set this path in the default configuration when the app starts.

Any recommended approach here?

Answer (score 0):

You make something misunderstood. The local Realm's path should be what you decide.

You can use `Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL` if you want to use the default storage location without changing the default. If there is a possibility of overwriting `defaultConfiguration` you can just save the value before overwriting. Or the following approach you are mentioned is also valid.

```
let documentsDirectoryUrl = FileManager.default.urls (for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask) .last!
documentsDirectoryUrl.appendingPathComponent ("default.realm")
```

That's because the default storage location on iOS is determined to be the above location.

Comment: Sorry for the delay accepting this, haven't had time to check it - will do as soon as possible!